# Definition of linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that each group of points below can be represented by a function, appropriately. Which of the functions below represents linear growth?

[image]

I believe there are 3, red orange and green. Are vertical lines linear functions?

Comment: it isn't even a function...

Comment: I agree ... but as the statement says that all groups are functions ...

Comment: I guess you assume that the points aren't actually colinear, but rather they just look like so...? This is a strange if not unorganized question.

Comment: Ummm... red and orange.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I believe that red is a constant function. Are they linear?

Comment: Yes.  $f(x) = c$ is linear.  Equal steps in $x$ lead to equal steps in the output, which in this case will be $0$.  The vertical green line is *not* a function, as there is no unique value for $f(1)$.

Comment: You can represent the green data as a function $x = f(y)$, which is linear. But "growth" indicates to me a description of how $y$ changes with $x$, so I would not call green "linear growth" myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orange dots and light red (pink?) dots represent linear growth as at any point $x$, $f(x)$ grows by the same amount per unit of time.

Using what I described above, it should be clear that the blue and maroon dots do not represent linear growth.

There are some ambiguities with respect to the green dots. I would not define those as representing a function since $f(1)$ does not map to a unique value.